# JavaScript Grammar: for/for-in loop rules?

Tags: javascript, grammar

I am writing a JavaScript parser, but the grammar rules for `for` loops is a bit confusing. [From the specs](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1153976512034/ecmascriptA3.g):

```
'for' LPAREN (
    (expressionNoln)? SEMI (expression)? SEMI (expression)? RPAREN statement
    | 'var' variableDeclarationListNoln SEMI (expression)? SEMI (expression)? RPAREN statement
    | leftHandSideExpression 'in' expression RPAREN statement
    | 'var' variableDeclarationNoln 'in' expression RPAREN statement
    )
```

I'm trying to figure out what the difference between `expressionNoln` and just a regular `expression`. And, in the process, figure out what's going on with `variableDeclartionNoln` and `variableDeclartionListNoln`.

The only difference I've found is a bit further down, between `relationalExpression` and `relationalExpressionNoln`. The latter rule is missing the `in` operator.

Did I get that right, or am I just confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I think you are confused because the ANTLR grammar has the identifier misspelled. It should be `variableDeclarationListNoIn` for "no in". ANTLR spells it `Noln` using an lowercase `l` instead of an uppercase `I`.

Removing the `in` from the expression is important to avoid an ambiguity for the special use of the `in` in the `for` statement.

BTW, your question implies that the link you give is the specification. It is not. It is a link to an example ANTLR grammar. The official standard can be found here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Answer (score 0):

I imagine each line represents the following `for`s:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(i);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(i);
for (i in obj) console.log(i + ': ' + obj[i]);
for (var i in obj) console.log(i + ': ' + obj[i]);
```

I'm not sure what `No Line` (which is what I imagine it stands for) means though.

```
SEMI = ';'    LPAREN = '('    RPAREN = ')'     ? = optional      | = or
```